# Calling the value of a column using Java Swing and with the oracle database

Tags: java, sql, oracle, swing

I wish you all a good day. I'm doing some kind of warehouse automation project, but I have a problem. My project has user and administrator login. With user login, a user will login and add products. So far everything is fine, but after logging in, I cannot add products for this user. For example, user A wants to put a chair in the warehouse. When he wants to log in with user A and add a chair, it will only belong to user A. It won't belong to other users like B, C, D because user A asked to add the chair. How can I do that?[image: This Picture]

My Oracle database code

```sql
CREATE TABLE Customer
(
    customerID INT NOT NULL,
    cFname     VARCHAR(20),
    cLname     VARCHAR(25),
    cAdress    VARCHAR2(40),
    cUsername  VARCHAR(10),
    cPassword  VARCHAR(10),
    cEmail     VARCHAR(15),
    CONSTRAINT c_ID PRIMARY KEY (customerID)
);

CREATE TABLE CustomerProducts
(
    productsID INT NOT NULL,
    customerID INT NOT NULL,
    pName      VARCHAR(30),
    pPCS       NUMBER,
    pDuration  VARCHAR(20),
    CONSTRAINT products_ID PRIMARY KEY (productsID),
    CONSTRAINT fk_Product FOREIGN KEY (customerID) REFERENCES Customer (customerID)
);


/*ALTER TABLE CUSTOMER MODIFY cEmail VARCHAR2(50);*/

CREATE TABLE Manager
(
    mID        INT NOT NULL,
    ProductsID INT NOT NULL,
    mFname     VARCHAR(20),
    mLname     VARCHAR(25),
    mAdress    VARCHAR2(40),
    mUsername  VARCHAR(10),
    mPassword  VARCHAR(10),
    mEmail     VARCHAR(15),
    mSalary    DECIMAL(8, 2),
    CONSTRAINT m_ID PRIMARY KEY (mID),
    CONSTRAINT fk_mProduct FOREIGN KEY (productsID) REFERENCES CustomerProducts (productsID)
);


CREATE TABLE Storages
(
    ssID       INT NOT NULL,
    mmID       INT NOT NULL,
    ProductsID INT NOT NULL,
    sCity      VARCHAR(30),
    sBlock     VARCHAR(15),
    sType      VARCHAR(20),
    CONSTRAINT s_ID PRIMARY KEY (ssID),
    CONSTRAINT fk_sProduct FOREIGN KEY (ProductsID) REFERENCES CUSTOMERPRODUCTS (productsID),
    CONSTRAINT fk_msProduct FOREIGN KEY (mmID) REFERENCES MANAGER (mID)
);
```

Java code

```java
private void urunekle_buttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{
    String product_name = urun_ad_text.getText();
    String product_pcs = urun_adet_text.getText();
    String timing = urun_suresi_text.getText();

    Customer_Login log = new Customer_Login();

    String customerID = log.getName();
    try {
        if (product_name.equals("") || product_pcs.equals("") || timing.equals("")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "WRONG!");
        } else {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");

            String sql =
                "INSERT INTO CustomerProducts (customerID,pName,pPCS,pDuration)" + " VALUES ('" + customerID + "','" + product_name + "', '" + product_pcs + "', '" + timing + "')";

            Connection con =
                DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XEPDB1",
                    "SYSTEM", "my-password");
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

            //   st.executeUpdate(sql);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, product_name + "  adlı ürün eklenmiştir.");
            //   UrunListeGuncelle();

        }

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hata: NE? " + ex.toString());
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
            "Veritabanına bağlantı sağlanamadı! " + ex.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Things you have to correct :

- in your `insert` query you are missing `customerID` field. And also use [named](https://www.infoworld.com/article/2077706/named-parameters-for-preparedstatement.html) parameters
- you create a new `Customer_Login`, I guess this is your `current user`? The way you get the current user here is not good. You have a to store the `current user` in a variable that could accessible from anywhere in your program
- simply rename your table `CustomerProducts` to `Products`